# F# Linq extension methods for custom type using linq query

Tags: linq, f#, extension-methods, monads

In C# I can enable monadic composition in Linq query for a custom type by implementing extension methods for `Select` and `SelectMany`, for example:

```c#
public static Either<L, R2> Select<L, R, R2>(this Either<L, R> @this, Func<R, R2> fn) => @this.Map(fn);
public static Either<L, R2> SelectMany<L, R, R2>(this Either<L, R> @this, Func<R, Either<L, R2>> fn) => @this.FlatMap(fn);
public static Either<L, R2> SelectMany<L, R, R1, R2>(this Either<L, R> @this, Func<R, Either<L, R1>> fn, Func<R, R1, R2> select) => @this.FlatMap(a => fn(a).FlatMap(b => select(a, b).ToEither<L, R2>()));
```

The third extension method is what enables monadic composition in Linq query on a similar basis to the `liftM` functions in Haskell, for example:

```cs
Either<L, C> LiftM2(Either<L, A> m1, Either<L, B> m2, Func<A, B, C> f) {
  return from a in m1
         from b in m2
         select Right(f(a, b));
}
```

My problem is however related to do achieving the outcome in F# by implementing extension methods for a custom `Either` type to enable monadic composition in Linq query.

Here is my definition of the `Either` type:

```ml
type Either<'l, 'r> =
  | Left of 'l
  | Right of 'r
```

First I added a functions for `map` and `flatmap` including custom operators for `map` as `<!>` and `flatmap` as `>>=` and `=<<`:

```ml
[<AutoOpen>]
module Either = 
  let lmap f e =
    match e with
    | Left(l) -> Left(f(l))
    | Right(r) -> Right(r)

  let rmap f e =
    match e with
    | Left(l) -> Left(l)
    | Right(r) -> Right(f(r))

  let map f e = rmap f e
  let inline (<!>) e f = map f e
  let inline (<!) a e = map >> constant

  let lflatmap f e = 
    match e with
    | Left(l) -> f(l)
    | Right(r) -> Right(r)

  let rflatmap f e =
    match e with
    | Left(l) -> Left(l)
    | Right(r) -> f(r)

  let flatmap f e = rflatmap f e
  let inline (>>=) f e = flatmap f e
  let inline (=<<) e f = flatmap f e
  let _return r = Right(r);
  let fail (l : string) = Left(l);
```

Then I added extension methods implementations; as I've garnered from other examples:

```ml
[<Extension>]
type EitherExtensions() =
  [<Extension>]
  static member inline Select(e: Either<'l, 'r>, f: 'r -> 's) = map f e
  static member inline SelectMany(e: Either<'l, 'r>, f: 'r -> Either<'l, 's>) = flatmap f e 
  static member inline SelectMany(e: Either<'l, 'r>, f: 'r -> Either<'l, 's>, select: 'r -> 's -> 't) = (f >>= e) =<< (fun s -> Either.Right(select(e, s)))
```

Problem is when I try to use this to implement `liftM`, `liftM2`, ... functions it doesn't appear to pick up these extension methods; instead it uses the extension methods for `System.Linq.IQueryable` and not my custom extension methods for Linq e.g. `SelectMany`

```ml
  let liftM f m1 = query { 
      for a in m1 do 
      select Right(f(a)) 
    }
```

The type of liftM resolve to:

```ml
liftM:
  f: a -> b,
  m1: System.Linq.IQueryable<'a>
-> System.Linq.IQueryable<Either<'c, 'a>>
```

Instead of:

```ml
liftM:
  f: a -> b,
  m1: Either<'c, 'a>
-> Either<'c, 'b>
```

I can of course implement `liftM` using either pattern matching, for example:

```ml
  let liftM2 f m1 m2 =
    match m1, m2 with
    | Right(a), Right(b) -> Right(f(a, b));
    | Left(a), _ -> Left(a)
    | _, Left(b) -> Left(b)
    ...
```

...or inline monadic composition, for example:

```ml
let liftM2 f m1 m2 = m1 =<< (fun a -> m2 =<< (fun b -> Right(f(a, b))))
```

However for both expediency and a bit knowledge I'd like to know how to achieve the same outcome as `C#` in `F#`

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to extend query expressions or do you just want monadic expressions for your `Either` type? In that case you should implement a [computation expression builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions) which implements the operations, then you can do e.g. `let liftM f m1 = either { let! a = m1; return (f a) }`

Comment: In C# the above implementation of the extension methods works as expected in Linq query without any additional implementation.  F# is something new for me, so its very likely that I am not using the correct syntax to access my three custom Linq query extensions for the `Either` type.  From what I could garner is that `query` would allow me to enter a Linq query; however that appears to only work with IQueryable. Does F# not have a seamless implementation of Linq extensions method like it is in C#.  Is a custom expression builder required in F#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# query syntax is based on a syntactic transformation as your example shows, in F# each monad instance is represented by an associated builder class which implements the required operations e.g. `seq`, `async`, `query`. You need to create an `either` builder which implements the required operations. For your example you only need a minimal implementation:

```
type EitherBuilder() = 
        member x.Bind(e, f) = flatmap f e
        member x.Return(value) = _return value
        member x.ReturnFrom(e) = e

let either = new EitherBuilder()
```

then you can use it to implement `liftM`:

```
let liftM f m1 = either { 
    let! a = m1 
    return (f a) 
}
```